# Do US students take USMLE exams of the same content like IMG (foreign) doctors?

Tags: health-education, different-national-health

Do US students take USMLE exams of the same content like IMG (foreign) doctors? Is it true that American students take USMLE separated in subjects not a as a whole set of 300 questions on all topics?

Answer (score 3):

> Do US students take USMLE exams of the same content like IMG (foreign) doctors?

Yes, they do.

> Is it true that American students take USMLE separated in subjects not a as a whole set of 300 questions on all topics?

It is false. It's the same.

- USMLE Step 1 :  single-day, composed of seven 40-question sections with a maximum 280 multiple-choice questions ([Source: usmle.org](http://www.usmle.org/step-1/))
- USMLE Step 2 CK: 9-hour single-day computer-based test composed of eight question sets with no more than 40 questions per set ([Source: usmle.org](http://www.usmle.org/step-2-ck/))
- USMLE Step 3: 2 days (9 hours and 8 hours) with the first day multiple choice questions, and second day multiple choice and computer-based (simulation-like) questions.  It's broken into hour chunks like Step 2 CK.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/quality-of-references/784#784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta].